# Can we pass whole data of csv from blob storage to on-premises SQL database using Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass all records of csv from blob storage to on-premises database of SQL using Azure data factory. I know how to pass data one by one using LookUp and Copy activity but I don't know how to pass all records of csv.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use copy activity with blob file as the source and Azure SQL DB table as sink wherein all records of file would be copied into table.

There is no need of a lookup activity

Answer (score 0):

You will have to **use copy activity** to copy data from azure blob storage to on-prem SQL database.
You can follow below steps:

**Step1:**
Select copy activity in data factory.

[image]

**Step2:**
Select Source dataset as azure blob storage

[image]

**Step3:**
Select on-prem sql database as a sink

[image]

**Step4:**
Click on import schema to do the mapping.

[image]

**Step5:**
Finally Execute Copy activity. No need to use lookup activity here.